# Editing Armor Stand Properties

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to change the lifetime of an armor stand like an item? Such as whenever it is placed, it dies two seconds after. I have already searched on Google, but didn't find anything.

Comment: What have you tried on your own?  We don't mind helping, but we generally expect askers to at least make an attempt to resolve their issue, first.  By including what you've already done, it will save answerers from repeating those same steps, and you'll get a better answer.  Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

Since Armor Stands don't have a natural despawn condition this can be done using scoreboards.

First execute this command once for setup:

`/scoreboard objectives add despawn dummy DespawnTimer`

This sets up a new dummy stat called DespawnTimer.

Next, set up a fill or setblock clock and attach 2 command blocks to it. Put these commands in the blocks:

`/scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand] despawn 1`

`/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,score_despawn_min=40]`

This will increase the "despawn" score of all armorstands once per tick (1/20 second) and kill the armorstand after 40 or more ticks (40/20 or 2 seconds).

Comment: 1.13 syntax for last command: `/kill @e[type=armor_stand,scores={despawn=40..}]`